# Read static ePassport (ISO 14443-4, MRTD) tag id via Android NFC

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard

Is it possible to read a STATIC tag id of ePassport? Each time I try to read tag id with my Android device it gives me a random one (it's described here: https://randomoracle.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/nfc-in-us-passports-verifying-the-random-id/).

I understand that MRTD application inside the card requires BAC to read personal information like name, nationality, image etc, but I don't need this data. I'm just wondering, if it's possible to get some stable card's ID to be sure, that it's the same card I've read a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible by intention. See [ICAO 9303, part 11](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf), chapter 4. 
What you attempt can't be distinguished from skimming, i. e. tracing, whether the same passport was already here and at which time, without any proof, that the card holder agreed (by presenting his or her card, so the terminal can read the optical information necessary for BAC).

Comment: Hi @guidot,
I having problem with AA, I am using jmrtd library and when I decrypt message from eMRTD, I initialize java Cipher like this `cipher = Cipher.getInstance(pubKey.getAlgorithm()`,
 then do operation follow AA specification in  ICAO 9303_p11, but AA is failed.
Do I need to initialize cipher with cryptographic mode such as CBC/ECB.. and padding ?